# Strange CSV result for quoted strings in go encoding/csv

Tags: string, csv, escaping, go

I have this little bit of code that kept me busy the whole weekend.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("./test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error: %s", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    w := csv.NewWriter(f)
    var record []string
    record = append(record, "Unquoted string")
    s := "Cr@zy text with , and \\ and \" etc"
    record = append(record, s)
    fmt.Println(record)
    w.Write(record)

    record = make([]string, 0)
    record = append(record, "Quoted string")
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%q", s)
    record = append(record, s)
    fmt.Println(record)
    w.Write(record)

    w.Flush()
}
```

When run it prints out:

```
[Unquoted string Cr@zy text with , and \ and " etc]
[Quoted string "Cr@zy text with , and \\ and \" etc"]
```

The second, quoted text is exactly what I would wish to see in the CSV, but instead I get this:

```
Unquoted string,"Cr@zy text with , and \ and "" etc"
Quoted string,"""Cr@zy text with , and \\ and \"" etc"""
```

Where do those extra quotes come from and how do I avoid them?
I have tried a number of things, including using strings.Quote and some such but I can't seem to find a perfect solution. Help, please?

Answer (score 6):

It's part of the standard for storing data as CSV. 
Double quote characters need to be escaped for parsing reasons.

> A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote characters.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

You don't really have to worry because the CSV reader un-escapes the double quote.

### Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
func checkError(e error){
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
func writeCSV(){
    fmt.Println("Writing csv")
    f, err := os.Create("./test.csv")
    checkError(err)
    defer f.Close()

    w := csv.NewWriter(f)
    s := "Cr@zy text with , and \\ and \" etc"
    record := []string{ 
      "Unquoted string",
      s,
    }
    fmt.Println(record)
    w.Write(record)

    record = []string{ 
      "Quoted string",
      fmt.Sprintf("%q",s),
    }
    fmt.Println(record)
    w.Write(record)
    w.Flush()
}
func readCSV(){
    fmt.Println("Reading csv")
    file, err := os.Open("./test.csv")
    defer file.Close();
    cr := csv.NewReader(file)
    records, err := cr.ReadAll()
    checkError(err)
    for _, record := range records {
        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}
func main() {
   writeCSV()
   readCSV()
}
```

### Output

```
Writing csv
[Unquoted string Cr@zy text with , and \ and " etc]
[Quoted string "Cr@zy text with , and \\ and \" etc"]
Reading csv
[Unquoted string Cr@zy text with , and \ and " etc]
[Quoted string "Cr@zy text with , and \\ and \" etc"]
```

Here's the code for the write function.
[func (w *Writer) Write(record []string) (err error)](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/csv/writer.go?s=1094:1145#L30)

Comment: I'd just add that real-life CSV producers/consumers seem to vary widely from the RFC's effort to define "standard CSV." If you want to exchange data with particular producers/consumers (mysqldump/mysqlimport, Excel/LibreOffice/Google Docs, etc.), you should actually test importing/exporting files from them with whichever types of special content that you actually expect to come up in your app (for example, ", ', =, é, 世界, CR/LF within a cell, empty string, NULL for SQL--you probably won't have to deal with all of those in your app; I'm just trying to throw out as many ideas as possible).

Comment: These are the reasons why, I get scared whenever a colleague says:
"reading CSV is too simple to use a library. It's just a comma separated string, after all"

Comment: What if you don't plan to read the csv with the csv package but you write a csv file to later send it to a user, who open it with excel?

Answer (score 5):

I have csv file with line with double quote string like:

> text;//*[@class="price"]/span;text

And csv Reader generate error to read csv file.
Helpful was:

```
reader := csv.NewReader(file)
reader.LazyQuotes = true
```

Answer (score -1):

The s variable's value is not what you think it is. http://play.golang.org/p/vAEYkINWnm